# how to compare string without using indexof and include in jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to compare some text using jquery for example

```
 var text = "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtActivity";
 var activityId = text.includes("txtActivity");
```

or

```
 var activityId = (isd.indexOf("txtActivity") > -1);
```

above code works successfully in crome and firefox
but it gives error in IE
is there any other way to fix it
please help

Comment: _but it gives error in IE_ -- Which error?

Comment: What error do you got in IE?

Comment: [`String.prototype.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes#Browser_compatibility) is not supported by IE. The `.indexOf()` version should work if `isd` is a string.

Comment: Java script error , Discription:- Object doesnot support property or method 'includes'/'indexof'

Comment: no its not supporting in IE both indexof and includes

Comment: Thats not true, `indexOf` works well in all browsers. If not, your code is having other issues. ;) @KalpeshKoli

Comment: the same code is working fine in crome and firefox

Comment: https://caniuse.com/#search=indexOf indexOf has been available since at least IE6.

Comment: Thankyou all for the answers...i think some thing is wrong with my code....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `indexOf` function works well in all browsers. Just remove the `inculdes` path and change the variable name to `text`:

```js
var text = "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtActivity";
var activityId = text.indexOf("txtActivity") > -1;

console.log(activityId);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use pattern match to do this:

```js
var text = "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtActivity";
if (/txtActivity/i.test(text)) {
       console.log("yes matched");
    }
else {
    console.log("not matched");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.. indexof working all browser..

```
<script>
var text = "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtActivity";

var n = text.indexOf("txtActivityda");
if(n!== -1)
{
console.log("found")
}
 else
{
console.log("not found")
}
</script>
```